# "package xxx.util does not exist" error while using cmake in a java project

Tags: java, makefile, cmake, package, manifest

I have to write a java project for a course and our professor requires us to use CMake as a build tool. 
In my Entry Point (main class) I want to use a class located in another package. While trying to compile it I get the following error message (attached below).

Using this wildcard import in Foo.java

```
import xxx.util.*;
```

helped, but I'm sure that this isn't the most elegant to achieve my goal.

I'm not able to figure out how to solve this problem as I get no problems using another built tool (maven) or manually compiling it. But as I must use CMake I hope that anyone out there had similar problems using this kind of project setup and is able to help me.

I listed all the relevant project information (structure, affected classes, CMakeLists.txt, ...) below.

Feel free to ask questions in the comments section in order to clear off any ambiguities.

Thank You!

Relevant Project structure:

```
.
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- build
|-- resources
|   |-- MANIFEST.MF
|   \-- sqlite.jar
|-- src
|   \-- xxx
|       |-- gui
|       |   \-- Foo.java
|       \-- util
|           |-- Bar.java
```

Foo.java:

```
package xxx.gui;

import xxx.util.Bar;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar bar = Bar.getBar(); //singleton 

    }
}
```

Bar.java:

```
package xxx.util;

public class Bar {

}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5) 
project(xxx LANGUAGES Java)
find_package(Java 1.8 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development)
include(UseJava)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "src/*.java") 
file(GLOB_RECURSE JARS "resources/sqlite*.jar")
add_jar(DataFX ${SOURCES} MANIFEST ./resources/MANIFEST.MF INCLUDE_JARS ${JARS}
ENTRY_POINT xxx.gui.Foo)
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Class-Path: ../resources/sqlite.jar
```

Relevant Error message:

```
gui/Foo.java error: package xxx.util does not exist
import xxx.util.Bar;
                  ^
gui/Foo.java error: cannot find symbol
        Bar bar = Bar
        ^
  symbol:   class Bar
  location: class Foo
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems quite logical to get this error. CMake as the other make utilities depend heavily on the order in which the classes get compiled.

From the makefile you've attached it's obvious that the make's entry point is 'xxx.gui.Foo' package problem is though that Foo.java has a dependency to Bar.java which at this point has not been compiled yet.

If you switch the order you could get this to work without any issue, that is Bar.java getting built before Foo.java.

All in all it's a good idea if you ever need to use make files to keep all the utility classes and in general all the classes with as little dependencies to other packages/classes on the top of you make file in order to minimize such problems.

Now, answering as to why you don't get this problem with Maven or javac, in case of the former it's a build tool thus it has a way no resolving all those on it's own. In case of the latter, I suppose that you already had both of the classes compiled hence why it's worked.

I hope the above solves your question.